# random backends in use_backend with map file

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

Imagine we have a backend file like this :

```
test.com backend_1
test.com backend_2
```

and we have something like this in our haproxy config file

```
frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   use_backend %[str(test.com),map(/etc/haproxy/testmap.map,default)]
```

this config is working **but always return backend_1 when u reach to test.com**

i want it to **round-robin the requests** to 2 backends with this mapfile

Answer (score 0):

There is a balance section to the backend configuration. You can see it in the docs here: https://www.haproxy.com/blog/the-four-essential-sections-of-an-haproxy-configuration/#balance

The backend file would look something like this:

```
backend test_com
  balance roundrobin
  server backend_1 10.0.1.3:80 
  server backend_2 10.0.1.4:80
```